# Unable to write new account information to a csv file

Tags: python, csv, password-manager

Working on making a password manager for a school project and I'm having trouble trying to add new account information to my password_manager.csv file. The information is being pulled from the other file when entered and it's printing successfully but when I try writing it to the csv file I get errors.

```
 import csv

 def createNewAccount(appName,userEmail,userName,userPassword):

    data = [appName,userEmail,userName,userPassword]

    print(data)
    
    with open('password_manager.csv','a') as csv_file:
        csv_writer = csv_file.write(csv_file, delimiter = '\t')
        csv_file.writerow(data)
```

Comment: post the error too.

Answer (score 0):

I can' test this because you didn't say exactly what errors you are getting (which you should always do when asking questions here). That said, it looks to me like you're not using the `csv` module correctly — see the [`csv.writer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer) documentation which contains example code.

The problem I see with your code are corrected in what's below:

```
import csv


def createNewAccount(appName, userEmail, userName, userPassword):

    data = [appName, userEmail, userName, userPassword]
    print(data)

    with open('password_manager.csv', 'a', newline='') as csv_file:
        csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter='\t')
        csv_writer.writerow(data)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    createNewAccount('appName1', 'userEmail1', 'userName1', 'userPassword1')
    createNewAccount('appName2', 'userEmail2', 'userName2', 'userPassword2')
```